# Colnames loop in R, combining characters with variables

Tags: r, variables, character

I'm new to R (and pretty new to programing in general) an am struggeling to write a loop to rename columns.

My goal is to rename the colums (f1w1, f1w2, f1w3, f2w1...)

Here's what I've got:

```
f <- 1
w <- 1
x <- 1

while(x<ncol(wdbc)){
  while (w < 4) {
  x <- (f-1)*3+w
  print (x)
  w <- w + 1
  colnames(wdbc)[x] <- ("f" f " w" w)  
  }

  w <- 1
  f <- f + 1
  }
```

f & w are the variables for the column names, x is the column I want to rename. R doesn't like how I tried to combine the variables with text in the name. I played around with "pasteO()" and "cat()" but I don't get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a loop. For example with `outer` :

```
f <- 1:4
w <- 1:3
nm <- c(t(outer(paste0('f', f), paste0('w', w), paste0)))
nm
#[1] "f1w1" "f1w2" "f1w3" "f2w1" "f2w2" "f2w3" "f3w1" "f3w2" "f3w3" "f4w1" "f4w2" "f4w3"
```

You can then assign these names as column names directly.

```
colnames(wdbc) <- nm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sapply` function to get the necessary column names.

```
f <- 1:4
w <- 1:3
new_col <- sapply(f, function(x) paste0("f",x,"w",w))
new_col 

#      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  
#[1,] "f1w1" "f2w1" "f3w1" "f4w1"
#[2,] "f1w2" "f2w2" "f3w2" "f4w2"
#[3,] "f1w3" "f2w3" "f3w3" "f4w3"
```